# How to determine who is the origin of every HTTP request

Tags: javascript, http, browser, cors, cross-domain

Is it true that the origin (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) is determined by the server who gave me the script file that sent the HTTP request?

---

If I'm right, then sometimes the script files of my website may come from multiple servers. The browser must have some notes on where each script file was downloaded from. Where Can I find this information in chrome latest? 
Also, how is it possible that I have a website that received his script files from server A and sends HTTP requests to server B (each server has a different domain), server A has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` and server B doesn't specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but everything is working?

If I'm wrong then how do I determine who is the origin of an HTTP request?

Comment: this: _Where Can I find this information in chrome latest?_ In the dev tools network panel.

Comment: I don't see that there. Can you specify where excatly?

Comment: The URL of every request is available...apparently you don't know the definition of Origin?

Comment: Also, the origin is established by the request URL used to gain access to the base resource (usually an HTML file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true that the origin (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) determines by the server who gave me the script file that sent the HTTP request?

No.

It allows JavaScript running on other websites to read data from your website where they normally would be blocked by the Same Origin Policy.

The origin of the JavaScript is irrelevant. It is the origin of the HTML document containing the `<script>` element that loaded the JavaScript that matters.

> The browser must have some notes on where each script file was downloaded from. Where Can I find this information in chrome latest?

The Network tab of the browser's developer tools.

> Also, how is it possible that I have a website that received his script files from server A and sends HTTP requests to server B (each server has a different domain), server A has Access-Control-Allow-Origin=* and server B doesn't specify Access-Control-Allow-Origin but everything is working?

The origin is determined by the URL of the HTML document, not the script.

> If I'm wrong then how do I determine who is the origin of an HTTP request?

A cross-origin request from XHR or Fetch will include an `Origin` HTTP request header.